# Redux store updates everything even if I just update a nested attribute?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, redux-toolkit

In my application, the user should have the possibility to edit his name. I thought about having his initial name as the default value of `useState()`. This works perfectly - the name is also updated as well.

```
function EditName(props) {
    const { navigation, dispatch, initFirstName } = props;

    const [text, setText] = useState(initFirstName);

    return (
      <>
        <Button title="Save" onPress={() => dispatch(updateFirstName(text))} />
        <TextInput
          style={{ height: 40, borderColor: 'gray', borderWidth: 1 }}
          onChangeText={(inp) => setText(inp)}
          value={text}
        />
      </>

    )


}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return (
    {
      initFirstName: state.user.data.firstName,
    }
  );
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(EditName);
```

But now I came across a problem if the user clicks on the save button and `dispatch(updateFirstName(text))` is handled. `text` is overwriten by `initFirstName` again.

My Redux (toolkit) store is structured as follows:

```
{
  data: {
    firstName: "Test"
  },
  updateFirstName: {
   pending: null,
   error: null,
  },    
}
```

The `updateFirstName(text)` method dispatches an action that sets `state.updateFirstName.pending = true;`. If I leave this out - everything works.

So I guess that a new reference to the store (state) is created and React thinks: "Oh - I got a new initFirstName" (beside it's still the same because the update hasn't happened yet).

What would be a better way to do this? What's a solution for this problem?

Comment: How your `EditName` Component is used?

Comment: That's a screen in my react native projekt. So it's defined within a StackNavigator.

Comment: I guess the problem is when you update the state the `EditName` components gets `rerenders` and you need to avoid it

Comment: Yes - I also think so. How would you avoid this or tackle this use-case in general?

Comment: I think you're using the `EditName` in a wrong way, I can't answer if I don't see a reproducible example of your codes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Taghi Khavari had a good guess: it had nothing to do with the code that I posted on StackOverflow - it was a React Navigation issue.

I use [nested navigators](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/nesting-navigators/) in my app. I declared the nested navigator inside my `App` function which resulted in the `EditName` component remounted multiple times after the state changed (I actually don't know why though).

When I declared the nested navigators OUTSIDE my App function (like in the following example), it worked and the component only got mounted once. Can anyone explain why?

```
function Home() {
  return (
    <NestedStack.Navigator>
      <NestedStack.Screen name="Profile" component={Profile} />
      <NestedStack.Screen name="Settings" component={Settings} />
    </NestedStack.Navigator>
  );
}

function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <RootStack.Navigator mode="modal">
        <RootStack.Screen
          name="Home"
          component={Home}
          options={{ headerShown: false }}
        />
        <RootStack.Screen name="EditPost" component={EditPost} />
      </RootStack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to create a function that will be called instead of assigning `onPress` an arrow function. Basically, the function will be called with the initial value of `text`.

Make sure you use the current value of `text`, try this:

```
const saveHandler = () => {
    dispatch(updateFirstName(text))
}
...
<Button title="Save" onPress={saveHandler} />
```